# How can i use Pub / Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to use Pub / Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage, on firebase i have storage files, i need to do any process  those process i storage in another fields on firebase as well, sometimes the process failed  so i need to use Pub / Sub Notifications for Cloud Storage to publish `OBJECT_FINALIZE`

to implement https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications, i need to create the topic, the suscription of the action by user.

where can i create the topic?, i am so confused with the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you run the command to create the GCS notification, if the topic-name does not exist it will automatically create it for you. So your first step is to create a GCS notification, passing a topic name and the event type on OBJECT_FINALIZE as parameters.

Example:

```
gsutil notification create -t <TOPIC_NAME> -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Note the parameters:

-t = Topic name

-e = Event type (Object finalize)

Once this part is done, your next step is to create a subscription to view the notifications sent to PubSub. The subscription is attached to the topic created above.

In this documentation, it explains how to create a subscription and also a Node.JS example with a push delivery: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub_create_push_subscription-nodejs

Comment: where can i apply this gsutil notification create -t <TOPIC_NAME> -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://BUCKET_NAME ?

Comment: Anywhere you would like (Cloud Shell or locally on your terminal, etc). If you are running it locally, you need to install gcloud SDK and init/authenticate to your GCP account. Cloud shell would give you the ability to have everything pre-set up for you and you basically need to switch to the project where you want to deploy the services.

Comment: with what action this pub/sub will be executed?

Comment: The notification will be triggered by the Event Type OBJECT_FINALIZE (which indicates on every new blob created/uploaded in the bucket). GCS notification will then send the metadata to PubSub which you could retrieve and do whatever is needed.

Comment: but i have three kind of files, how can i specify the type of the file?

Comment: In my example, the notifications will be triggered on any blob (file) created in the bucket. However, you could filter and acknowledge only the messages which matches with the three type of files you have. You could also specify the notification only on certain prefixed files. Here is the full list with all parameters for the GCS notifications: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification

Comment: No worries @register, Did you get it to work? Once you understand the idea, it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: can you explain me with more details please, how can i create a subscription, is necesary create a topic, so on?

Comment: When you run the gsutil command I wrote on my answer, it will automatically create the topic for you (based on the -t TOPIC_NAME parameter). The subscription you can create here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#creating_subscriptions

Comment: last question please, how can i get BUCKET_NAME ?

Comment: If you are on Firebase console, go to menu Storage and the bucket name will be listed there, starting with 'gs' example gs://bucket-name.appspot.com

Comment: You can list GCS notifications with gsutil, gsutil notification list gs://<bucket_name>

Comment: with this line i am creating a subscription await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).createSubscription(subscriptionName); what is subscriptionName, where can i get that name?